# HF push_to_hub API through Google Colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I am using Google Colab to push my fine tuned model to the Hub. When I run the model.fit() function, a output directory was created on the Colab my drive and the model(Bert-base-uncased) begins to train on my datasets(glue- sst2) for 2 epochs. As the 2nd epoch progress bar run to completion, the training keeps running for hours and eventually crashed and the whole process failed, then Colab displays can't connect to GPU as backend for that day. I have tried this twice but keeps getting the same results. Could it be the Colab GPU isn’t enough to push the model to the Hub or am doing something wrong?

```
from datasets import load_dataset
raw_datasets = load_dataset('glue', 'sst2')

checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def tokenizer_function(example):
  return tokenizer(example['sentence'], truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(tokenizer_function, batched= True)
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")

tf_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids","token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=['labels'],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=30,
)

tf_validation_dataset = tokenized_datasets["validation"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids","token_type_ids"],
    label_cols=['labels'],
    shuffle=False,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=30,
)

num_epochs = 2
num_train_steps = len(tf_train_dataset) * num_epochs
lr_scheduler = PolynomialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=2e-5, end_learning_rate=0.0, decay_steps=num_train_steps
)
opt = Adam(learning_rate=lr_scheduler)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=opt, metrics= ['accuracy'])

callbacks = PushToHubCallback(
    "bert-fine-tuned_sst2", save_strategy="epoch", tokenizer=tokenizer
)

model.fit(tf_train_dataset, validation_data=tf_validation_dataset, epochs=1, callbacks=callbacks)  #this is where am having issues
```

The notebook crashed and model failed to push to the hugging face hub

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like the problem isn't with the `push_to_hub` API. Instead, I think your intuition about your notebook resources not being sufficient is right. When you observe the resource utilization in your notebook (in the top right, there's usually an icon with RAM and CPU usage) does it max out?

One solution to try might be to impose a max length on your tokenized arrays and to use batching: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/colab-ram-crash-error-fine-tuning-roberta-in-colab/2830.